# Printing out select parameters from a multiple constructor parameter

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I'm struggling with getting the desired output they are asking for.

**Here is my main method:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PersonalInformationCollection {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // implement here your program that uses the PersonalInformation class

    ArrayList<PersonalInformation> infoCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("First name: ");
        String firstName = scanner.nextLine();

        if (firstName.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }

        System.out.print("Last name: ");
        String lastName = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Identification number: ");
        String idNumber = scanner.nextLine();

        infoCollection.add(new PersonalInformation(firstName, lastName, idNumber));
    }

    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < infoCollection.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(infoCollection.get(0));
    }
    //System.out.println("Total number of persons: " + infoCollection.size());

}
```

**Here is the "PersonalInformation" class:**

```
public class PersonalInformation {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String identificationNumber;

public PersonalInformation(String firstName, String lastName, String identificationNumber) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.identificationNumber = identificationNumber;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public String getIdentificationNumber() {
    return identificationNumber;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.lastName + ", " + this.firstName + " (" + this.identificationNumber + ")";
}
```

**The output should look like this:**

```
First name: Jean

Last name: Bartik

Identification number: 271224

First name: Betty

Last name: Holberton

Identification number: 070317

First name:

Jean Bartik

Betty Holberton
```

**My question is:**

- How can I just print out the first and the last name ***WITHOUT tinkering*** with the **PersonalInformation** class?

As of now, the `idNumber` is still included in the answer.

I've tried to create a different contractor with only two parameters but, it won't let me do that.

Comment: Just change the `toString` to `return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName`

Comment: Due to the way the program is set up, it doesn't want me messing with that part of the program. I'm only able to write in the main method.

Comment: So change the second loop, print manually the parts you want from list.get(i). And look about for each loop on the web ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chenged the print to this :

```
   for (int i = 0; i < infoCollection.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("First name: "+infoCollection.get(i).getFirstName());
        System.out.println("Last name: "+infoCollection.get(i).getLastName());
        System.out.println("Identification number:"+infoCollection.get(i).getIdentificationNumber());
    }
```

Input and Output :

```
First name: Jean
Last name: Bartik
Identification number: 271224
First name: Betty
Last name: Holberton
Identification number: 070317
First name: 

First name: Jean
Last name: Bartik
Identification number:271224
First name: Betty
Last name: Holberton
Identification number:070317
```

Comment: Please confirm my answer to the community, if it helps you, thank you!

Comment: @TibetanMassive also, have a look to other answers. If you will find them valuable you could use as well.

Answer (score 1):

For others taking the Mooc Fi course like OP and unfamiliar with the advanced solutions being offered, this is the suggested solution:

```
        for (PersonalInformation info : infoCollection) {

                System.out.println(info.getFirstName() + " " + info.getLastName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a separate method which prints the list with the desired format:

```
printPersonalInformation(infoCollection);
```

Instead of iterating the collection manually and printing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < infoCollection.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(infoCollection.get(0));
}
```

You should add it to `PersonalInformationCollection` class.
So you don't need to modify original model implementation.
You just change the way how it is printed to console.

Implementation should be something like:

```
private static void printPersonalInformation(List<PersonalInformation> list) {
    List<String> piList = new ArrayList<>();
    list.forEach(l -> {
        System.out.printf("First name: %s%n%nLast name: %s%n%nIdentity number: %s%n%n",
                l.getFirstName(), l.getLastName(), l.getIdentificationNumber());
        piList.add(String.format("%s %s", l.getFirstName(), l.getLastName()));
    });

    System.out.println("First name:");
    piList.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

***Output:***

```
First name: Jean
Last name: Bartik
Identity number: 271224
First name: Betty
Last name: Holberton
Identity number: 070317
First name:
Jean Bartik
Betty Holberton
```

If you need to print exactly as you showed at the question the format should be following:

```
System.out.printf("First name: %s\n\nLast name: %s\n\nIdentity number: %s\n\n",
```

And

```
System.out.println("First name:\n");
piList.forEach(l -> {
    System.out.printf("%s\n\n", l);
});
```

***Output for such case***:

```
First name: Jean

Last name: Bartik

Identity number: 271224
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex, `\\([^\\(]*\\)` to replace the `identificationNumber` part.

Replace

```
System.out.println(infoCollection.get(0));
```

with

```
System.out.println(infoCollection.get(0).toString().replaceAll("\\([^\\(]*\\)", ""));
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

1. `\(` matches the left parenthesis.
2. `[^)]*` matches all characters except the right parenthesis.
3. `\)` matches the right parenthesis.

**Alternatively:**

You can replace

```
System.out.println(infoCollection.get(0));
```

with

```
PersonalInformation info = infoCollection.get(0);
System.out.println(info.getFirstName() + ", " + info.getLastName());
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is
>   How can I just print out the first and the last name WITHOUT tinkering with the personalInformation class? As of now, the idNumber is still included in the answer.

You are printing firstName, lastName & identificationNumber because you implemented your PersonalInformation class' `public String toString()` as such.

Note that `toString()` gives you a String representation of your object. So when you print the PersonalInformation object like this:

```
System.out.println(infoCollection.get(0));
```

It will invoke your class' `tostring()` method.

---

Assuming it is part of the requirement to include all 3 attributes (firstName, lastName & identificationNumber) in your `toString()` method, then to print just the firstName and lastName, just do it as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < infoCollection.size(); i++) {
    //depending how you want it to display
    System.out.println(infoCollection.getFirstName() + ", " + infoCollection.getLastName());
}
```

> I've tried to create a different contractor with only two parameters but, it won't let me do that.

For what you wanted, you do not need to create another constructor. If you do not wish to use the `getFirstName()` and `getLastName()`, you can write a `getFullName()`:

```
public class PersonalInformation {
    pubic String getFullName(){
        //depending how you want it to display
        return this.getFirstName() + ", " + this.getLastName(); 
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {   
        //To print out the full name..
        for (int i = 0; i < infoCollection.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(infoCollection.getFullName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Checkout System.out.format method. Example in below link
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html

Comment: Using System.out.format you could change your output without tinkering with the PersonalInformation class. Not sure why it was down voted.